# Long company names slightly break layout on careers.stackoverflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image]

The right-hand end is clipped.

[Here is the link](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=&location=spain&range=20) to the page, if you want to try it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was addressed at some point.  It should look good in modern browsers with the exception of the case of having a long job title, long company name *and* a Joel Test score (the Joel Test score occasionally wraps to the next line).